# Cucumber steps for two different drivers

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I am using two different browsers, capybara poltergeist and a selenium driver (not the capybara selenium driver).

In my cucumber tests I have steps that look like this:

```
#for selenium
When /^I go to url$/ do |url|
  @driver.get url
end

#for capybara
When /^I visit url$/ do |url|
  visit url
end
```

My number of tests are growing and this form of work around (naming the steps differently)
is growing.

I want to have a more elegant way of doing this, specially when it comes to clicking of buttons.

Comment: Can you give some context to why you need to support both Capybara and Selenium-WebDriver? It seems strange that you would not just use Capybara. Understanding why you are trying to do this might help give better solutions.

Comment: We used Selenium-WebDriver for a few years then started to also use capybara poltergeist (for tests that ran faster headless and for monitoring the network traffic). We already had too many Selenium-WebDriver tests to rewrite everything using the capybara selenium driver. We started to use different step definitions (the walk around) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a method called visit and code it like this:

```
def visit (url)
   @driver.get url
end
```

Then when you are not using the capybara dsl, the method you defined is called.

Answer (score 0):

Id probably remove redundant cucumber step match since last loaded wins. But within one of your regex matches id do a Case statement... E.g
    when(/^i go to url using "selenium"$/)     do |url,app| 
    case app 
    when 'selenium' @driver.get url 
    when 'capybara' visit url 
    else #default to selenium @driver.get      url 
    end

Comment: case statements would work, but I don't think its the best way to go, because it will result in long step definitions with lots of repetition (not DRY). I was looking for more of a solution that would bind the capybara api with the selenium api... so that when I write "visit url" the framework knows that it should do "@driver.get url"